# Python Split Treemap Image into Constituent Parts

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, split, treemap

I'm looking to split the attached treemap in its constituent parts (each rectangle is separated by white space and contains text).

The code I've tried extracts only 7 out of the 25 available...this is now at the limits of my opencv knowledge.[image]

```
import cv2

image = cv2.imread('page_sample.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (3,3), 0)
thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(blur,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV,9,3)

cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]

ROI_number = 0
for c in cnts:
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    peri = cv2.arcLength(c, True)
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 0.05 * peri, True)
    #if len(approx) == 4 and area > 2200:
    if len(approx) >= 0 and area > 1000:
        x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(approx)
        ROI = image[y:y+h, x:x+w]
        cv2.imwrite('ROI_{}.png'.format(ROI_number), ROI)
        ROI_number += 1
```

Comment: recursive algorithm. consider a ROI/slice, initially everything. calculate minimums (assuming white cuts) for each row and column (`region.minimum(axis=0/1)`). where you have a straight cut, *all* the pixels are white (so is the minimum). that's where you cut *once*. then recurse into both pieces. with with binarized data or grayscale data. do you need a fleshed out answer?

Comment: wrong function, it's gonna be `region.min(...)` but oh well

Comment: `findContours` could be used but it might be a headache here. invert and binarize picture so the boxes are white and gaps are black, then run with `RETR_EXTERNAL` so the text in there doesn't distract. that should give all the boxes.

Answer (score 1):

Result:
[image: result]

Assumptions:

- space is filled as is typical for tree maps, so it can be split accordingly
- gaps are white and 1 pixel wide
- no padding around it all, no other distractions (I cropped your picture)

Principle:

Recursive algorithm. Consider a region, initially everything. Calculate minimums for each row and column. Where all pixels along a line are white (`True`), the minimum is also white (`True`), and that's where you can cut straight through. Then recurse into both subregions. If no such cuts, it's a "leaf".

Code:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os
import sys
from math import *
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv
import pprint

np.set_printoptions(suppress=True, linewidth=120)

def make_cut(mask, region):
    (i0, i1, j0, j1) = region

    crop = mask[i0:i1, j0:j1]

    rows = crop.min(axis=1)
    cols = crop.min(axis=0)

    if rows.any():
        (indices,) = rows.nonzero()
        i = indices[0]

        return [
            (i0,   i0+i, j0, j1),
            (i0+i+1, i1, j0, j1)
        ]

    elif cols.any():
        (indices,) = cols.nonzero()
        j = indices[0]

        return [
            (i0, i1, j0,   j0+j),
            (i0, i1, j0+j+1, j1)
        ]

    else:
        # no cuts
        return None


im = cv.imread("wabXk.png")
(height, width) = im.shape[:2]

# there must be no stuff around the block of tiles
# no white margin, no lines, nothing. clean.
mask = (im == 255).all(axis=2)

# (i0, i1, j0, j1)
to_test = [(0, height, 0, width)]
result = [] # treat as stack (or queue, either is fine)

while to_test:
    region = to_test.pop(0)

    subregions = make_cut(mask, region)
    print(region, "=>", subregions)

    if subregions is None:
        result.append(region)
    else:
        to_test[:0] = subregions # insert in front


pprint.pprint(result)

canvas = im / np.float32(255 * 2)

for i,region in enumerate(result):
    (i0, i1, j0, j1) = region

    cv.rectangle(canvas,
        pt1=(j0+1, i0+1),
        pt2=(j1-2, i1-2),
        color=(1,1,1))

    cv.putText(canvas,
        text=f"{i+1}",
        org=(j0+10, i0+40),
        fontFace=cv.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,
        fontScale=1,
        color=(1,1,1),
        thickness=2)

cv.imshow("result", canvas)
cv.waitKey(-1)
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Thank you so much...worked like a dream...I now have 25 individual rectangles...

If I want to save each rectangle, as in the original post how would I do this...as I'm not ofay with the openCV library...

Thanks again...

Comment: slicing, of the original image, not the `mask`. the bounds of each slice are given. that is numpy, not OpenCV. for saving an image, `imwrite` (OpenCV).